# Whats the use of social network login or connect

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, oauth, social-networking

I have seen in many websites, that they uses facebook login button, yahoo login button and twitter login button

1. what is the use of those
2. Will those sites store the authenticated user's id as username, if so what they use for password ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very good explanation here for "Login with Facebook" buttons that you see around: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

"Facebook helps you simplify and enhance user registration and sign-in by using Facebook as your login system. Users no longer need to fill in yet another registration form or remember another username and password to use your site. As long as the user is signed into Facebook, they are automatically signed into your site as well. Using Facebook for login provides you with all the information you need to create a social, personalized experience from the moment the user visits your site in their browser."

Comment: thanks for the info, so what happens in terms of password ? because i authenticate a user and get his/her info about address, name etcs but not the password and i do registration but my question is will the sites validate the user when they login the next time as below ?  1-authenticate....2-compare the field stored in database with the details received through api  ?

Comment: still can't able to get the work flow

Comment: Most sites store user info after the first login (i.e. Name, email, etc.) at their own database and compare a unique field (i.e. email) with that of the api provided e-mail and understand that it is the same user logging in. Basically you never store the user's password in your database. You use the api as the authentication source.